# What determines which monitor a program will open up on in a dual monitor setup?

Tags: multiple-monitors

How do i control which monitor a given program will open up on in a dual monitor setup?

Currently, when i open an application (such as firefox, word, excel) the monitor in which it opens up on is seemingly random. What determines which window that application will open on and how can i change it such that it will only open on a given monitor?

Thanks,

-Faken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 'remembers' the last position of a window and will start it right there the next time, or so the theory goes.

i do, however, recommend a decent window manager, allowing to apply rules (such as position alignment, transparency, etc.) to a program window.

Eusing's **[Auto Window Manager](http://www.eusing.com/WindowManager/WindowManager.htm)** is free

My recommendation would be **[Actual Window Manager](http://www.actualtools.com/windowmanager/)** (shareware, $49.95, 60 days evaluation period), a 'must have' for multi-monitor environments.