# When opening a program via the start menu, how can I force it to open on the same monitor as the start menu?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, start-menu, classic-shell

I use a laptop running on Microsoft Windows 10 with an external monitor. I.e, I have 2 monitors: the built-in display of the laptop (which is the primary monitor) + 1 external monitor. I use [Classic Shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_Shell). From time to time, when I open the start menu on the external monitor and open a program, the program's window opens on the primary monitor and not the external monitor.

When opening a program via the start menu, how can I force it to open on the same monitor as the start menu?

Comment: Closest you can get is a program that stores window positions and sizes and automagicallly places them there (probably).

Comment: DisplayFusion comes to mind but there are others. Unfortunately you'd need the paid version https://www.displayfusion.com/Compare/

Comment: A free, but far less userfriendly, option is NirCmd https://superuser.com/a/1514021/1482432

Comment: UltraMon can do the same thing https://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/overview/ It hasn't been updated in a while, but it should still work. https://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/tour/shortcuts_shellex_window.png

Comment: Note that DisplayFusion is reasonably priced ($29 USD for a lifetime license) and has a 2 week trial version https://www.displayfusion.com/Discussions/View/displayfusion-pro-trial-licenses-now-available/?ID=57cfcf9c-f1ad-4977-bdcb-47ba87e2209d I'd try that first because NirCmd is not as userfriendly and UltraMon has not been updated in a while. I've used DisplayFusion for quite a few years and it works fine. If you google "displayfusion alternatives" you'll probably find more similar programs.